# { error: 'Service does not exist', code: 'SoftLayer_Exception_Public',

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer_OpenIdConnect/getHardwareCount/

We have below code to get details:

```
slClient
.auth(SL_USER_NAME, SL_USER_APIKEY)
.path('User_Customer', userID, 'getHardwareCount');
```

to get hardwareacount but intermittently we get error :

> [2019-04-08T20:24:02.116] [INFO] sl - Error in:
>   softlayer.js::getUserHardwareCount: [2019-04-08T20:24:02.116] [INFO]
>   sl - { error: 'Service does not exist', code:
>   'SoftLayer_Exception_Public', statusCode: 404 }

Any insights on this ?

Comment: it seems the issue is in the client, you put `getHardwareCount` but looks like the client is sending `getUserHardwareCount` to the server, I recommend you to debug/check what is the REST request the client is sending. Now you said you are using `SoftLayer_User_Customer_OpenIdConnect` but in your code you put `SoftLayer_User_Customer`

Comment: Even if I use SoftLayer_User_Customer it gives me same error . I tried with this two SoftLayer_User_Customer and SoftLayer_User_Customer_OpenIdConnect . Both shows method to get count. And about getUserHardwareCount this is function I am using in nodejs and at error block it says this function has error for method I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting the error `Service does not exist` since I can see you are using the correct service name `User_Customer`, and about the error `Error in: softlayer.js::getUserHardwareCount` is because that method doesn't exists in the SLDN API.

To test I downloaded the client https://www.npmjs.com/package/softlayer-node and used the following script which worked for me, I hope this could help you.

```js
var SoftLayer = require('softlayer-node');
var client = new SoftLayer();
var USER_NAME = 'set-me';
var API_KEY = 'set-me';
var userID = 123456;

client
  .auth(USER_NAME, API_KEY)
  .path('User_Customer', userID, 'getHardwareCount')
  .get()
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

You can also test it using the following REST calls in any browser

```
https://$USER_NAME:$API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer/$USER_ID/getHardwareCount
```

```
https://$USER_NAME:$API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_User_Customer_OpenIdConnect/$USER_ID/getHardwareCount
```